# Is there a way to convert actual street map coordinates to a set of GPS coordinates?

Tags: gps, gis

I wonder is there a way to convert actual street map coordinates to a set of [GPS coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System).  I was thinking if I have a set of GPS coordinates on the corners of a rectangular street map, I could virtually put a GPS coordinate to any point in that area. It is logical but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: This might be better asked on [gis.se]

Comment: By "GPS coordinates" I assumed (as did Wikipedia) that you meant WGS-84.  What does "street map coordinates" mean?

Comment: Could you clarify the question?  I don't know what you mean by "actual street map coordinates" and "virtually put".

Comment: @MichaelKristofik The idea I think is that he has a two-dimensional map (of some streets say) with the GPS coordinates of the 4 corners, and wants to be able to project the GPS coordinates onto the interior of the map. The issue with this of course is that the coordinates don't follow a standard grid layout but "warp" according to the longitude/latitude lines that they follow.

Comment: You can use GRASS or ArcGIS to geo-reference your map by identifying the coordinates of the four corners. You can select tie-points to pre-referenced imagery (in Google Earth) or find known features that you can reference (intersections, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The [Geotools](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide) Java project has all the tools you need to transform from one coordinate system to another. I'm not aware of anything similar in C++ though I'm afraid.

There are an absolute wealth of coordinate systems out there (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system), so you'd need to be more specific about the format in which you have your street map coordinates for me to give any more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I get the concept. You need two ingredients for that:
>    1. Scale and..
>    2. Corner sample.
>
> It's easy to make a program to offset your marked points on the map
>   but these requires the "Scale" (ex. 1-inch : 121001-meters) and the
>   sample of "coordinate" in at least one of any of the four corners
>   (top-left,top-right,bottom-left,bottom-right) for use to offset and
>   get.
>
> Out of these variables needed, we could easily extract to get the
>   coords marked on your map.

MAJOR EDIT:
(Note: Disregard what I've written earlier above)
Variables:

```
mw = 2d mapwidth       
mh = 2d mapheight     
x = your 2d x coordinate             
y = your 2d y coordinate          
lat = latitude (our N or ?)          
lon = longitude (our N or ?)
```

Formula:

```
lat = 180 + ( (x / mw) * 360) )          
long = 90 + ( (y / mh) * 360) )
```

Explanation:
Following the formulas which are used:

```
x = (mw) * (180 + latitude) / 360                   
y = (mh) * (90 + longitude) / 180
```

I've personally transposed the formula above to find our latitude and longitude.
I hope this solves your problem and this is the appropriate answer for your question.
Don't forget to up my answer to save my honor from the humiliation earlier. jk. :)

Comment: This doesn't take into account the fact that GPS coordinates will not line up linearly within a two dimensional grid.

Comment: -1, it's not necessarily that simple.  The earth is not flat, so coordinates will not scale linearly within a 2D grid.  Worse, it's not a sphere either.  WGS-84 uses an ellipsoid approximation for the shape of the earth.  Projecting points from some reference depends on where you are on the earth and how far you're going.

Comment: he said it's a street map so it's meant as 2d I guess.

Comment: If it's a "street" map, then a slight error might not affect the approximation much. Unless the whole street you can't see end to end against the horizon, which is I think even a small town area can't.

Comment: Thanks for all who tried to give me hints; sorry to confuse some of you; yes I want to get the WGS84 or GPS coordinate from a 2D street map, but I want to automate it; if I have GPS coordinates on the corners of the map- is it possible to design a formula which will calculate GPS coordinate out of any location in that 2D map - how ? hopefully it will involve spheroid because I live in the equator.

Comment: As you can see I've edited my answer above. please refer to it now.

Comment: yes thanks Jes, you are such a helpful person - but sorry say I have 4 GPS corner coordinates 106.36'.0"E, 6.14'.0"; 106.37'.0"E, 6.14'.0"; 106.36'.0"E, 6.15'.0"; 106.37'.0"E, 6.15'.0"; the how to use your formulas ? all in cm : mw=20.8 and mh=15.8 say the target is at x1,y1 = 10, 10.9 Question what is the GPS coord of x1, y1 ?

Comment: Then just convert the GPS corner coordinates to 2d coordinates.. Then:
    lat=106.36'.0"E,long=6.14'.0" and anything else will become.....
    1. x=16.54524 and y=8.43895
    2. x=16.54582 and y=8.43895
    3. x=16.54524 and y=8.43983

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to say thank you again, for your last explanation.  But I guess your answer still does not use earth as spheroid but as a sphere. I am still thinking what is the best way to do this.

Comment: If the 2d image was scaled properly it might match up to the pixel. i mean if you have a 2d map of the whole world which is somehow stretched correctly you might end up with correct outcome , but this map will look stupid kind of !